# Linux sometimes recognizes twice the number of cores

Tags: linux, core, htop

Recently, my department bought two pretty good (HP Z840 Workstation) second hand computers, supposedly identical. I installed Linux (CentOS 9) in both of them, no problem. When I view the CPU info with `inxi -C`, I get that indeed they both have Intex Xeon E5-2699 v4 with 2x22 cores. Now, when I use other commands to view system information (such as `neofetch` or even `htop`) I am shown that one of them has 44 cores (alright) and the other has 88 (not alright).

I have done some reading online and it seems to be related to hyperthreading, but I am quite amateur in these affairs so I don't really know about such things. And actually I wouldn't mind it, but there's a problem.

I usually require basic parallelization in processes in Python (using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`), and I noticed that the same script runs twice slower if I allow the faulty computer to use as many "cores" as it wants (and apparently Python views the fake 88 cores  instead of the true 44, as confirmed by `multiprocessing.cpu_count`). I know I could just limit the number of cores with the option `max_workers=44`, but I would like to solve the issue once and for all.

What should I do? Does it have to do with the BIOS? Or is it a Linux config thing?

EDIT: here is the filtered output of `/proc/cpuinfo` requested

- Computer 1 (faulty):

```
processor   : 0
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0

processor   : 1
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2

processor   : 2
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4

processor   : 3
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6

processor   : 4
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 8
initial apicid  : 8

processor   : 5
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 10
initial apicid  : 10

processor   : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 16

processor   : 7
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 18

processor   : 8
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 20
initial apicid  : 20

processor   : 9
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 22
initial apicid  : 22

processor   : 10
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 24
initial apicid  : 24

processor   : 11
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 16
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32

processor   : 12
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 17
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 34
initial apicid  : 34

processor   : 13
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 18
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 36
initial apicid  : 36

processor   : 14
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 19
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 38
initial apicid  : 38

processor   : 15
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 20
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 40
initial apicid  : 40

processor   : 16
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 21
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 42
initial apicid  : 42

processor   : 17
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 24
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 48
initial apicid  : 48

processor   : 18
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 25
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 50
initial apicid  : 50

processor   : 19
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 26
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 52
initial apicid  : 52

processor   : 20
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 27
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 54
initial apicid  : 54

processor   : 21
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 28
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 56
initial apicid  : 56

processor   : 22
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 64
initial apicid  : 64

processor   : 23
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 66
initial apicid  : 66

processor   : 24
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 68
initial apicid  : 68

processor   : 25
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 70
initial apicid  : 70

processor   : 26
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 72
initial apicid  : 72

processor   : 27
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 74
initial apicid  : 74

processor   : 28
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 80
initial apicid  : 80

processor   : 29
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 82
initial apicid  : 82

processor   : 30
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 84
initial apicid  : 84

processor   : 31
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 86
initial apicid  : 86

processor   : 32
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 88
initial apicid  : 88

processor   : 33
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 16
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 96
initial apicid  : 96

processor   : 34
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 17
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 98
initial apicid  : 98

processor   : 35
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 18
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 100
initial apicid  : 100

processor   : 36
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 19
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 102
initial apicid  : 102

processor   : 37
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 20
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 104
initial apicid  : 104

processor   : 38
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 21
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 106
initial apicid  : 106

processor   : 39
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 24
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 112
initial apicid  : 112

processor   : 40
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 25
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 114
initial apicid  : 114

processor   : 41
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 26
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 116
initial apicid  : 116

processor   : 42
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 27
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 118
initial apicid  : 118

processor   : 43
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 28
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 120
initial apicid  : 120

processor   : 44
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1

processor   : 45
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3

processor   : 46
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5

processor   : 47
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7

processor   : 48
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 9
initial apicid  : 9

processor   : 49
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 11
initial apicid  : 11

processor   : 50
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 17

processor   : 51
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 19

processor   : 52
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 21
initial apicid  : 21

processor   : 53
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 23
initial apicid  : 23

processor   : 54
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 25
initial apicid  : 25

processor   : 55
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 16
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 33
initial apicid  : 33

processor   : 56
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 17
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 35
initial apicid  : 35

processor   : 57
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 18
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 37
initial apicid  : 37

processor   : 58
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 19
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 39
initial apicid  : 39

processor   : 59
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 20
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 41
initial apicid  : 41

processor   : 60
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 21
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 43
initial apicid  : 43

processor   : 61
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 24
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 49
initial apicid  : 49

processor   : 62
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 25
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 51
initial apicid  : 51

processor   : 63
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 26
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 53
initial apicid  : 53

processor   : 64
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 27
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 55
initial apicid  : 55

processor   : 65
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 28
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 57
initial apicid  : 57

processor   : 66
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 65
initial apicid  : 65

processor   : 67
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 67
initial apicid  : 67

processor   : 68
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 69
initial apicid  : 69

processor   : 69
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 71
initial apicid  : 71

processor   : 70
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 73
initial apicid  : 73

processor   : 71
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 75
initial apicid  : 75

processor   : 72
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 81
initial apicid  : 81

processor   : 73
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 83
initial apicid  : 83

processor   : 74
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 85
initial apicid  : 85

processor   : 75
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 87
initial apicid  : 87

processor   : 76
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 89
initial apicid  : 89

processor   : 77
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 16
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 97
initial apicid  : 97

processor   : 78
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 17
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 99
initial apicid  : 99

processor   : 79
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 18
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 101
initial apicid  : 101

processor   : 80
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 19
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 103
initial apicid  : 103

processor   : 81
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 20
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 105
initial apicid  : 105

processor   : 82
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 21
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 107
initial apicid  : 107

processor   : 83
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 24
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 113
initial apicid  : 113

processor   : 84
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 25
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 115
initial apicid  : 115

processor   : 85
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 26
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 117
initial apicid  : 117

processor   : 86
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 27
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 119
initial apicid  : 119

processor   : 87
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb00001f
physical id : 1
siblings    : 44
core id     : 28
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 121
initial apicid  : 121
```

- Computer 2:

```
processor   : 0
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0

processor   : 1
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2

processor   : 2
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4

processor   : 3
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6

processor   : 4
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 8
initial apicid  : 8

processor   : 5
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 10
initial apicid  : 10

processor   : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 16

processor   : 7
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 18

processor   : 8
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 20
initial apicid  : 20

processor   : 9
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 22
initial apicid  : 22

processor   : 10
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 24
initial apicid  : 24

processor   : 11
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 16
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32

processor   : 12
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 17
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 34
initial apicid  : 34

processor   : 13
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 18
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 36
initial apicid  : 36

processor   : 14
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 19
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 38
initial apicid  : 38

processor   : 15
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 20
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 40
initial apicid  : 40

processor   : 16
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 21
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 42
initial apicid  : 42

processor   : 17
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 24
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 48
initial apicid  : 48

processor   : 18
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 25
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 50
initial apicid  : 50

processor   : 19
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 26
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 52
initial apicid  : 52

processor   : 20
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 27
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 54
initial apicid  : 54

processor   : 21
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 0
siblings    : 22
core id     : 28
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 56
initial apicid  : 56

processor   : 22
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 64
initial apicid  : 64

processor   : 23
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 66
initial apicid  : 66

processor   : 24
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 68
initial apicid  : 68

processor   : 25
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 70
initial apicid  : 70

processor   : 26
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 72
initial apicid  : 72

processor   : 27
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 74
initial apicid  : 74

processor   : 28
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 8
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 80
initial apicid  : 80

processor   : 29
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 9
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 82
initial apicid  : 82

processor   : 30
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 10
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 84
initial apicid  : 84

processor   : 31
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 11
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 86
initial apicid  : 86

processor   : 32
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 12
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 88
initial apicid  : 88

processor   : 33
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 16
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 96
initial apicid  : 96

processor   : 34
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 17
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 98
initial apicid  : 98

processor   : 35
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 18
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 100
initial apicid  : 100

processor   : 36
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 19
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 102
initial apicid  : 102

processor   : 37
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 20
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 104
initial apicid  : 104

processor   : 38
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 21
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 106
initial apicid  : 106

processor   : 39
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 24
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 112
initial apicid  : 112

processor   : 40
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 25
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 114
initial apicid  : 114

processor   : 41
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 26
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 116
initial apicid  : 116

processor   : 42
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 27
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 118
initial apicid  : 118

processor   : 43
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
microcode   : 0xb000038
physical id : 1
siblings    : 22
core id     : 28
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 120
initial apicid  : 120
```

Comment: What htop shows is not exactly cores, it's "logical CPUs". How many sockets vs cores vs threads does `lscpu` report, in both situations?

Comment: Yes this is probably related to hyperthreading. A CPU may have 22 physical cores, but report 44 logical cores to the OS. The OS is able to make the difference AFAIK. If the two machines are identical but report a different number of logical cores, then maybe the hyperthreading is disabled on one of them. You may explore the BIOS setting to enable/disable hyperthreading.

Comment: Please note that the “v4” is part of the CPU model name. Please provide the full output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "(processor|siblings|core id|cpu cores|apicid|model|microcode|physical id|^$)"`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your replies. @DanielB, you are right, I missed the v4. I have also added the output you requested. Regarding the `lscpu` information, they both show 2 sockets,  22 cores per socket. They differ in the number of threads per core, 2 in the faulty against 1 in the normal one.

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding the lscpu information, they both show 2 sockets, 22 cores per socket. They differ in the number of threads per core, 2 in the faulty against 1 in the normal one.

So you have 22-core CPUs **with hyper-threading enabled** on one machine, but disabled on the other. With HT (aka SMT) active, the OS handles each core as two "logical CPUs".

Hyper-threading (HT) aka Simultaneous multithreading (SMT) might be enabled/disabled either through a firmware setting, or a Linux kernel boot option (which if I remember correctly is `nosmt`?), or *possibly* even permanently disabled by certain firmware versions.